# check if entity exist and then delete it in one transaction in spring app

Tags: java, spring, transactions

i have a services layer and a repository layer in my spring boot application (i use also spring data, mvc etc)

before deleting an entity from the database, I want to check if such an entity exists and if not, then throw an EntityNotFoundException

for example my repository:

```
public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Long> {

    @Query("from Room r left join fetch r.messages where r.id = :rId")
    Optional<Room> findByIdWithMessages(@Param("rId") long id);

    @Override
    List<Room> findAll();
}
```

and service:

```
@Service
@Loggable
public class RoomService implements GenericService<Room> {

    private final RoomRepository roomRepository;
    private final RoomDtoMapper roomMapper;

    public RoomService(RoomRepository roomRepository, RoomDtoMapper roomMapper) {
        this.roomRepository = roomRepository;
        this.roomMapper = roomMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Room getById(long id) {
        return roomRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
                () -> new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("room with id = %d wasn't found", id)));
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Room room) {
        getById(room.getId());
        roomRepository.delete(room);
    }
}
```

In this example in the delete method, I call the

> getById(room.getId())

(so that it throws an EntityNotFoundException if the entity does not exist.)

before

> roomRepository.delete(room);

it seems to me that such code is not thread-safe and the operation is not atomic
(because at the moment when in this thread at the moment of checking another request from another thread may already delete the same entity)
and I don't know if I'm doing the right thing

maybe i should add the @Transactional annotation?
would it allow me to make the method atomic?
like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(Room room) {
    getById(room.getId());
    roomRepository.delete(room);
}
```

maybe i should set some kind of isolation level?

Comment: *maybe i should add the @Transactional annotation? * not maybe... YOu should add the `@Transactional` to your service layer to make operations atomic. Also why the find and delete? Why not just call `delete` which basically does all of this for you already? You can convert the `EmptyResultSetException` into your `EntityNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

you can test if your object needed, exist or not by autowiring the repository injected (in your case is RoomRepository e.g) and (insted User in my exmaple you can use Room): for example:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> deletUserById(Long id) {
    if (userrRepository.findById(id).isPresent()) {
        userrRepository.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("User deleted with success");
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body("user to be deleted not exist");
    }
}
```